# How to average score with array like: [[score, count], [score, count]]

Tags: ruby

I have an array like:

```
[[score, count], [score, count]]
```

I need to add all the scores and divide by all the counts :)

Here is an example

```
[[10, 2], [5, 2]] : (10x2 + 5x2)/4 = 7.5
```

Comment: example output will be helpful..

Comment: Example output is a Float average score.

Comment: *by all the counts* means *by the sum of count*.. right ?

Comment: Yeah.. see my example, above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ary = [[10, 2], [5, 2]]
total_score = ary.reduce(0) { |sum, (a, b)| sum + a * b }
total_count = ary.reduce(0) { |sum, a| sum + a.last }
avg = total_score/total_count.to_f
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [[10, 2], [5, 2]]
#=> [[10, 2], [5, 2]]

arr.reduce(0) { |acc,(x,y)| acc + x * y }.to_f /  arr.reduce(0) { |acc,(_,y)| acc + y }
#=> 7.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes a single pass through the array.

```
arr = [[10, 2], [5, 2], [3, 4]]

tot, div = arr.reduce([0,0]) { |(tot, div), (score, count)|
             [tot + (score * count), div + count] }
  #=> [42, 8]
tot/div.to_f #=> 5.25
```

This calculates

```
tot => 0 + 10*2 + 5*2 + 3*4 => 42
div => 0 +   2  +  2  +  4  =>  8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ary = [[400, 5], [240, 4]]
total_score = ary.map{|a| a.first*a.last}.sum
total_count = ary.map(&:last).sum
avg = total_score/total_count.to_f
```

Comment: In Ruby we don't have `sum` method.

Comment: That's correct, but I am using Rails, where it is available. So either way

Answer (score 0):

```
data.inject(0) { |score, (x, y)| score + x * y }.to_f / data.inject(0) { |count, (_, y)| count + y }
```